# Nginx - changing root folder for specific url gives 404 error

Tags: nginx, web-server, web-hosting

I am trying to arrange a location block for anyone get through `mydomain.com/game/admin` url, make sure the nginx server to pull the content exists in `/var/www/html/my-cakephp-app/` directory. My application is built using cakephp framework and its directory structure is shown below:

> - /var/www/html/my-cakephp-app/
>
>   - admin
>
>     - Config
>     - Console
>     - Controller
>     - View
>     - webroot (App entry-point index.php file exists in this directory)

Also I have static html/css website located in the `/var/www/html` directory. So anyone with `mydomain.com` url can see that website too.

Here is my current nginx server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    
    location /game/admin {
            return 301 /game/admin/;
    }

    location /game/admin/ {

                root /var/www/html/my-cakephp-app/admin/webroot;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /game/admin/index.php$is_args$args;
  
                location ~* \.php(/|$) {
                  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               } 

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

With this setup, my static web-site working fine. But cakephp application gives 404 not found error in browser. No any errors in the nginx/error.log.

But when I run with below nginx configuration, my application works fine. But I have to get rid of my html/css site.I am planning to upgrade html/css app with a wordpress site. So I should have the ability to run the wordpress site as the parent.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/html/my-cakephp-app/admin/webroot;
    
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
 
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        autoindex on;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I couldn't think of what I have done wrong with the first server block. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main problems are:

- the outer `location ~ \.php$` block takes precedence over the `location /game/admin/` block unless you use the `^~` modifier (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details)
- the `root` directive generates a path to the file by simple concatenation, so your controller is expected to be located at `/var/www/html/my-cakephp-app/admin/webroot/game/admin/index.php` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details)

---

One option is to move the project so that the directory structure matches the URI structure. This could be achieved using a symbolic link which points `/var/www/html/game/admin` to `/var/www/html/my-cakephp-app/admin/webroot` in which case the outer `location ~ \.php$` block will be able to execute both projects.

---

Another option is the `alias` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

```
location ^~ /game/admin {
    alias /var/www/html/my-cakephp-app/admin/webroot;

    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /game/admin/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

Note that `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` will not work with `alias` and that `$request_filename` should be used instead.

I avoid using `alias` and `try_files` together due to [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of the `if` directive.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly fine. I was wasting my time with root directive whole day. Anyways, thank you so much for the good explanation.